# Афёра или афера?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Насколько мне помнится, правильно все-таки "афера" через Е, но ведь большинство говорит "афёра". Почему так?

Comment: Такое распространенное «афёра» некоторое время было в ходу и даже встречается в Большой советской энциклопедии. Несмотря на это, современные словари не рекомендуют использовать этот вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант **АФЕРА** является единственно правильным употреблением, афёра - разг.

Answer (score 2):

В современных словарях единственно допустимым вариантом признаётся **афера**.

В словаре Ивановой Т.Ф. "Новый орфоэпический словарь русского языка" слово **афера** помечено восклицательным знаком, указывающим на "строгую нормативность и обязательность" такого произношения.

То же видим в грамматическом словаре А.А. Зализняка.

Comment: словарь Зализняка (от автора, ревностно критиковавшего любительскую лингвистику и забывшего к старости, при этом, что всем известный и популярный словарь Даля был создан и издан именно любителями русской словесности), -- как и любое иное издание -- иной словарь или энциклопедия отдельного автора, а также публикации от малой группы участников-составителей, -- является (в основном) лишь частным мнением или списанным у кого-то "плагиатом" (зачастую и с повторением прежних ошибок). Никакие условности с правилами или печатными изданиями, не могут быть и не являются "нормой" для выражения

Comment: @Али для справки: ААЗ очень уважал и часто использовал в своей работе словарь Даля, при этом не забывая указать на замечательное языковое чутье его автора. Если вы не знаете, о чем пишете, лучше не писать вовсе, по моему мнению; если же, как говорится, руки чешутся, то стоит хотя бы «Из заметок о любительской лингвистики» прочитать...

Answer (score -1):

Именно **афёра** по-русски, и слова аферистичный план, аферистический или аферист и т.д. тут не уместны в качестве проверки, как:

- стёб (а не стеб) стебущий, стебущийся или стебаться;
- трёп (а не треп) трепаться и трепач;
- гнёт (а не гнет) гнетущий;
- лёд (а не лед) ледяной или ледник и ледниковый;
- мёд (а не мед) медоносный или медовый;
- лёт (а не лет) летать или летящий;
- манёвр (а не маневр) из той же оперы и т.д.

К сожалению, проблемы с программированием на начальной стадии развития интернета вывели из оборота многие русские слова с буквой Ё, так как употребить её было проблематично: из за отсутствия такой клавиши и некой упрощённости письма научными работниками. Была бы буква Ё в интернете изначально, то мы бы увидели на много больше слов не через Е. Если нету в текстах Ять, букву Ё надо писать, а не Е лепить где ни попадя.

- афёра -- жульническое предприятие, мошенничество; сомнительная торговая или иная сделка. Аферист -- человек, совершающий А., живущий ими. Большая советская энциклопедия. -- М.: Советская энциклопедия 1969-1978 гг.
- афёра... Б.З. Букчина, Л.П. Калакуцкая, Л.К. Чельцова "Письма об орфографии". Москва, из-во "Наука", 1969 г.
- афёра... "Вопросы культуры речи", Часть 8. Изд-во "Академии наук СССР", 1967 г.
- афёра... "Начальная школа". Из-во "Просвещение", 1962 г.
- афёра... Пот. Афёра - выгодная, незаконная сделка; обман, «плутня» (см. «арап»). «Ты на аферу-то не лезь!» «Афера» (с жестом или присвистом произносимое, означает: «врешь, не проведешь!»). "Русская речь". 1990 г.
- афёра... Г. Миньковский, В. Туманов "Суд в СССР и в странах капитала". Государственное издательство юридической литературы, 1954 г.
- афёра... В.И. Хомицкий "Вторая книга пьес репертуара Передвижного театра". Из-во передвижного театра, 1973 г.
- афёра... Процесс же этот — была бы великолепная афёра (Ипполитъ Иванычъ произносилъ афёра, а не афера); но дело как бы расклеивается. П. Воробыкин "Отечественные записки №1, январь: Дельцы (роман в шести книгах)". Санкт-Петербург 1873 год.

Примеры о якобы французском произношении слова через Е, являются натянутыми и необоснованными. Мы говорим и пишем по-русски, а не по-французски. Однако, и тут необходимы уточнения, так как по-их(нему) -- по-французски, -- слово "affaire" не звучит даже близко навязываемому нам варианту слова "афе́ра", и не имеет ударения на букву и звук "Е" -- которого там (у них) даже нет: французское произношение -- а.фэр. Кроме того, если кто вспомнит про Чехова и ему подобных, то напомню: те авторы писали свои произведения в форме дореволюционной орфографии -- с ятями. И как было сообщено выше, следует: ...если в тексте нету Ять, букву Ё надо писать, а не Е лепить где ни-попадя (в переводах с русского на русский). ​Ять, это современное "Е", а дореволюционное "Е" как раз -- ближе к Ё. ​Дореволюционно слово писалось не через Ять, а через Е, что соответствует в произношении -- Ё.

Глупо предлагать проверочным слово аферист для афёра (как и наоборот), особенно при демонстрации ряда примеров точно такого же изменения русских слов, как трёп (трепач), мёд (медведь -- ведающий мёд), лёд, гнёт и т.д. Демонстрация в некое доказательство современных словарей не уместно. К примеру словарь Зализняка (от автора, ревностно критиковавшего любительскую лингвистику и забывшего к старости, при этом, что всем известный и популярный словарь Даля был создан и издан именно любителями русской словесности), -- как и любое иное издание -- иной словарь или энциклопедия отдельного автора, а также публикации от малой группы участников-составителей, -- является (в основном) лишь частным мнением или списанным у кого-то "плагиатом" (зачастую и с повторением прежних ошибок). Никакие условности с правилами или печатными изданиями, не могут быть и не являются "нормой" для выражения мысли русского народа по рождению и воспитанию, и только сам человек определяет -- как и что ему говорить или писать. В советское время, слово афёра (через Ё) было широко распространено в речи народа. Кстати,.. так же говорили многие и до революции 17-го года, что отражено в одном из приведённых выше источников информации -- в подтверждение распространённости варианта слова с буквой Ё ("Отечественные записки №1, январь: Дельцы (роман в шести книгах)". Санкт-Петербург 1873 год.). Кроме того, если в обращении используется два варианта слова (вне зависимости от указаний и рекомендаций отдельных), то и условной нормой в современных словарях должны быть два варианта (что не редкость и для иных слов русского языка).

> Насколько мне помнится, правильно все-таки "афера" через Е, но ведь
>   большинство говорит "афёра". Почему так?

Почему говорят - или почему правильно? 
Правильно именно потому, что нет никаких оснований говорить там Ё - кроме частично закрепившейся традиции говорить неправильно. 
А вот почему говорят... Это странно, ведь именно в этом слове французское произношение affaire очень близко к русскому [ф'э], только ф там не смягчается. Но, видимо естественное в русском смягчение "ф" привело и к колебанию в качестве гласного.

Это можно было бы счесть до некоторой степени достаточным объяснением, если бы не контрпример со словом "шофёр" (chauffeur), которое, в противоположность афере, без всяких видимых причин в просторечии теряет своё законное Ё. Видимо, тут какие-то высшие силы вмешались, рационального объяснения этим двум взаимоисключающим тенденциям у меня нет.

Comment: И вовсе не из той же оперы!

Comment: Французское слово *affaire* произносится, если грубо перевести в русскую фонетическую систему, примерно так: *а'фэр* (апостроф указывает на следующий ударный слог). Это как раз соответствует русскому звуку *э* (звука *е*, о котором вы говорите, нет) — [аф'эра] (апостроф указывает на мягкость предшествующего согласного).

Comment: Ваши измышления о корреляции дореформенного написания ятя с произношением далеко не точны: *плед*, в котором не писалось ятя (так как это заимствование, как и *афера*), сейчас звучит вовсе не как *плёд* (нельзя даже сказать, что его произношение "ближе к Ё").

Comment: Для справки: ААЗ очень уважал и часто использовал в своей работе словарь Даля, при этом не забывая указать на замечательное языковое чутье его автора. Если вы не знаете, о чем пишете, лучше не писать вовсе, по моему мнению; если же, как говорится, руки чешутся, то стоит хотя бы «Из заметок о любительской лингвистики» прочитать...

Comment: @Aer, ещё раз -- а.фэр, где точка в международном фонетическом алфавите определяет некое прерывание в произношении слова или краткую паузу, -- не имеет акцентное ударения именно на второй слог.

Comment: Али, вы путаете разные понятия: пауза паузой, а ударение ударением. Утверждение, что слово *affaire* во фр. не имеет акцентного ударения (следует из ваших сообщений), ошибочно.

Comment: @Аег, слово пледъ, а не плѣдъ, прозносилось и писалось именно ближе к E/Э, а не к ЙЕ. К сожалению тут нет возможности продемонстрировать запись произношения для наглядности.

Comment: Во-первых, я не писал слово *плед* в дореформенной орфографии, а просто указал на отсутствие ятя. Во-вторых, никакого *ЙЭ* в нем не может быть, так как отсутствуют условия для появления йота. Ну, я и говорю, что произносилось оно не через *Ё*, а через *Е*... Ненужно тут никакой наглядности. Просто вы утверждаете, что «если в тексте нету Ять, букву Ё надо писать, а не Е лепить где ни-попадя (в переводах с русского на русский)», а я указываю на ложность утверждения.